# Why is my question being voted to close right now?

Tags: support

I do not know what's wrong with this:

https://superuser.com/questions/260317/comprehensive-online-product-database-with-decent-search-function

Comment: Why do people vote down questions like these? They OP is trying to learn something here, and voting down his question on meta isn't very helpful, even if it's in the FAQ. (I think we should instead appreciate the fact that the OP actually asked.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: They spent the time clicking on the "meta" link and bothering other people, so why didn't they click the "faq" link that's right next to it and clearly offers faster answers?

Comment: @Hello71: I don't know, I wasn't the OP. But I don't think a speedy reply was an issue here, and -- judging from the OP's comment to Sathya's answer and the fact that the OP joined *before* WebApps launched -- I don't think he deserves a downvote for assuming that he could still post here, even if it was in the FAQ.

Comment: @Mehrdad: This policy has been around for quite a while, long before WebApps or even Area 51 were around.

Comment: @Hello71: Okay, I didn't know that. But I still think two downvotes was kind of harsh, given that he OP actually cared enough to ask.

Comment: @Mehrdad @Hell71 Thank you for your concern.  Admittedly, I haven't  read the FAQ very thoroughly.  But I did look at it to see if hardware related questions are allowed.  On the other hand I'm used to the fact that people vote up and down rather casually, resulting in a bias towards the extremes of the scale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> and it is **not about** … [..]
>
> - websites or web services

Comment: But many questions here are somehow related to websites.  I consider the question hardware related, which is explicitly included in the FAQ.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: If it's about if/whether website for x exists or how can I make use of feature x in a website/webapp - [WebApps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) covers that. Older questions exist because of change in policy that was done quite some time ago,.